# How do you change the formatting of the code generation strategy?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Right now, when I click "Generate Model from Database" on the edmx schema instead of getting this:

```
 public int ID { get; set; }
 public int LocationID { get; set; }
 public string LocationDescription { get; set; }
```

I get this:

```
 public int ID { get; set; }

 public int LocationID { get; set; }

 public string LocationDescription { get; set; }
```

What's causing it to put spaces between properties. Is there a way to change how the Code Generation Strategy formats the code generated?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't want to get THIS far just to remove carriage return between properties that are automatically generated.

Furthermore, why would you even do this ? Your not suppose to touch this file unless doing something REALLY specific. So, as the auto generated code is not to be touched in any way, why are you even looking at it?

If this is annoying you to the point where you REALLY can't go on without removing carriage returns in those files, well, I'll be glad to show you how.

Here you go :

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2008/09/01/Customize-Code-Generation-in-EF.aspx?m=1

And I wish you the best of luck... Cause you'll need it.